# In Ruby how do I generate a long string of repeated text?

Tags: ruby, string

What is the best way to generate a long string quickly in ruby?  This works, but is very slow:

```
str = ""
length = 100000
(1..length).each {|i| str += "0"}
```

I've also noticed that creating a string of a decent length and then appending that to an existing string up to the desired length works much faster:

```
str = ""
incrementor = ""
length = 100000
(1..1000).each {|i| incrementor += "0"}
(1..100).each {|i| str += incrementor}
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: The best way would be to use JRuby and use StringBuffer. Oooooh.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

```
str = "0" * 999999
```

Comment: Indeed, very weird, look how different and elegant  looks in Python: `str = "0" * 999999` ;)

Comment: Why is the order important with Ruby? When I do `99999 * "0"` I get `TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum`

Comment: @Steven From Ruby's perspective, `"0" * 999999` is treated as `"0".*(999999)` where `*` is a method in the `String` class. That method accepts numbers as valid arguments to perform string replication. When you reverse the expression, we get `999999.*("0")`. Now we are talking about the `*` method in the `FixNum` class, and that method refuses to take strings as arguments. It certainly could (for example, automatically making a best-effort to convert the argument to a FixNum) but the language designers decided against embracing Ruby's Perlish inspirations too fully.

Answer (score 11):

Another relatively quick option is

```
str = '%0999999d' % 0
```

Though benchmarking

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm(9)  do |x|
  x.report('format  :') { '%099999999d' % 0 }
  x.report('multiply:') { '0' * 99999999 }
end
```

Shows that multiplication is still faster

```
               user     system      total        real
format  :  0.300000   0.080000   0.380000 (  0.405345)
multiply:  0.080000   0.080000   0.160000 (  0.172504)
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I can't seem to get it to work for anything other than '0'. What do I do if I want 100 r's?

Comment: It won't work with other symbols because it's taking advantage of number padding in format strings. Numbers can be padded with 0's in front or back (for decimals) without changing the value, r's don't work like that.