# convert a number into another one made up of 9s

Tags: ruby

I have a number *N* and I have to create another number *X* of length *N* made by 9s

```
length = 6

some code
output_number = 999999
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296994/in-ruby-how-do-i-generate-a-long-string-of-repeated-text

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Here's one: `6.times.map { ((r = (1..9).to_a.sample(4).join.to_i) - r.digits.join.to_i).abs.digits.sum.digits.sum }.join.to_i
 #=> 999999`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
('9' * 6).to_i
#=> 999999
```

or

```
10**6 - 1
#=> 999999
```

Comment: Fine, but I think #2 would suffice.